# Requests for Instagram Access token

Tags: json, django, python-requests, instagram-api

I am working on Instagram API in Django(python)

I am getting code from

```
'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%s&response_type=code&redirect_uri=%s' % (INSTAGRAM_APP_CONSUMER_KEY, redirect_uri)
```

but when i am exchanging code for access token code is failing

```
# All arguments are valid 
def execute(self, code, redirect_uri, app_id, app_secret):
    exchange_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token'
    try:
        #Update :  get request to post
        r = requests.post(exchange_url, params={
            'client_id': app_id,
            'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
            'client_secret': app_secret,
            'code': code,
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code'

        })
        #print(r)
        #print(json.loads(r))
        print(r.json())
        return r.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

r.json() gives simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1

Update 1 : r.json() works after request changed from get to post but error 
           message comming 'You must provide a client_id'

Please let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: what happens if you print only `r`?

Comment: <Response [405]>

Comment: well thats an error [Error 405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405). Read over this and find another way to request whatever you need. hope this helps

Comment: also is it possible that you need to make a POST request rather than a get?

Comment: On post request response 400 and r.json() works but 'error_message': 'You must provide a client_id'  and i am providing client_id

Comment: well check your `client_id` it might be null, do a `print app_id` before the POST request and see if you are indeed sending nothing as client_id otherwise I dont know how to help.

Comment: all arguments are proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it requires data in `post` data, not in query params.
Try this :

```
your_post_data = {'client_id': '', ... }
r = requests.post('your_url', data=your_post_data)
```

Ref: [Python Requests Docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)